# Add extra properties to regionprops in skimage

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision, scikit-image, superpixels

I'm using the `regionprops` function from the `scikit-imag`e (or `skimage`) package to compute region features of a segmented image using the SLIC superpixel algorithm from the same package.

I need additional features than those computed in the fucntion, mainly : standrad deviation, skewness, kurtosis.

I modified the source code of `_regionprops.py` using the other features as template in order to include those properties :

```
    @property
    def sd_intensity(self):
        return np.std(self.intensity_image[self.image])

    @property
    def skew_intensity(self):
        return skew(self.intensity_image[self.image])
```

I know this is bad practice, and not a long term solution because my code won't be able to run on another machine or if i update skimage.

I discovered that the function `skimage.measure.regionprops()` has a `extra_properties=None` parameter, which according to the doc:

> Add extra property computation functions that are not included with skimage.

My question is : Can I get a working example with np.std ? I don't really know how to use this parameter.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`extra_properties` just takes a list of functions with region mask and intensity image as arguments. Here's a quick example:

```
from skimage import data, util
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops
import numpy as np
img = util.img_as_ubyte(data.coins()) > 110
label_img = label(img, connectivity=img.ndim)

def sd_intensity(regionmask, intensity_image):
        return np.std(intensity_image[regionmask])

def skew_intensity(regionmask, intensity_image):
        return skew(intensity_image[regionmask])
    
props = regionprops(label_img, intensity_image=img,
                    extra_properties=(sd_intensity, skew_intensity))
```

You can now access your extra properties using your function names

```
props[0].sd_intensity
>>> 0.4847985617008998
```

EDIT 08/28/2021, updated the example to actually compute region local statistics as pointed out by @CrisLuengo and @JDWarner (thank you guys)

Comment: Thanks I thought I had the answer but i forgot to add `intensity_image` for my functions. Question is answered.

Answer (score 4):

The above accepted answer by filippo is (edit: was - now corrected; original post follows) subtly incorrect in a dangerous way.  The statistics returned with that answer are applied to the intensities of the *entire bounding box*, not the masked and labeled subregion!  The extended functions passed need to use `regionmask` to slice the intensity image.  Complete corrected example:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import skew
from skimage import data, util
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops

img = util.img_as_ubyte(data.coins()) > 110
label_img = label(img, connectivity=img.ndim)

def sd_intensity(regionmask, intensity_image):
        return np.std(intensity_image[regionmask])  # Note slicing

def skew_intensity(regionmask, intensity_image):
        return skew(intensity_image[regionmask])   # Note slicing
    
props = regionprops(label_img, intensity_image=img,
                    extra_properties=(sd_intensity, skew_intensity))
```

This will properly produce local statistics for just the labeled regions of the intensity image.

I do not yet have sufficient "reputation" to comment on that answer so submitting as a separate answer since this is an important distinction.

Comment: thank you! see the updated answer and comments, please let me know if anything is still wrong

Answer (score 1):

I found a reference in the doc of the dev branch of `skimage`. It's included in the 0.18.dev0 version

Code source : https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/measure/_regionprops.py#L1028

Link to documentation : https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops

```
# Add custom measurements by passing functions as ``extra_properties``
from skimage import data, util
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops
import numpy as np

img = util.img_as_ubyte(data.coins()) > 110
label_img = label(img, connectivity=img.ndim)

def pixelcount(regionmask):
    return np.sum(regionmask)

props = regionprops(label_img, extra_properties=(pixelcount,))
```

```
props[0].pixelcount
    7741
props[1]['pixelcount']
    42
```