# How to get center of irregular shape with skimage regionprops?

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

I'm using Skimage `regionprops` to find the center of objects, and then opencv to write text in the middle of the object. However, some of the objects are irregular in shape and the centroid coordinates are outside of the object. How can I get the "center" of the object when it is irregular such that the center is inside the object?

Comment: If the centroid is inside the object (as you said), then just use the centroid. You can test if the point is inside a polygon with cv2.pointPolygonTest(). Get the contour of the object and then use this test.

Comment: Thanks for cv2.pointPolygonTest(), that'll be super useful. But what do I do if the centroid isn't in the polygon? How can find a point that is inside the polygon?

Comment: Compute the distance from the point to the closest point on the polygon and move the point to the closest point and then a little more. Test again and iterate if needed.

Comment: Intesting, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is called the [medoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medoid) and [currently doesn't exist in scikit-image](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/5273), though we are interested in adding an implementation.

Note that as of v0.18, regionprops [lets you add extra properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63481913/add-extra-properties-to-regionprops-in-skimage), so if you find a good implementation you can start using it straight away.